# system-installation ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded the ISO image from the official Ubuntu page.
I have created a USB to install with the Universal USB Installer software.
At the time of installation, I get an error that I do not understand.

[image: error installation]

Comment: Can you describe more detailed: You see this error after installation with first boot or at the time of installation? Can reboot and login to command line without network connection? Do you try install ubuntu without downloading additional 3rd party software (option)?

Comment: I have installed windows 7 and working ok (pirate). It is the first time I am installing    ubuntu. My connection to internet is wired in this device (home internet).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the firmware files for your wireless adapter:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

If you can access command line try installing the open source b43 driver:

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```